# Testing that an Asp.Net Web Form Validator is Set Up Correctly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, validation, webforms

I am working in a web forms project and I'm constrained to use validation controls such as compare validator like:

```
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="SomeValidator" ValueToCompare="Some
   Value" ControlToValidate="MyControl" ErrorMessage="Some Error    
   Message." Operator="NotEqual" runat="server"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

I would rather split validation rules out but I can't in this case.

I would at least like to test that the properties on the validator control are correct.

For example, I would like test like:

SomeValidator_Has_A_ControlToValdiate_MyControl or
SomeValidator_Has_Value_To_Compare_SomeValue etc

Can this be done using reflection and can someone show me a sample please?

Or is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears top be that without using MVP etc, web forms simply can't be tested in the way I would like.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if we have a simple option here but since FxCop is meant for rules on managed code. I think you should be able to write some custom rule and build what you are looking for.